# Force ipv4 connections in .NET?

Tags: .net, ipv4

I am running a console app on my server and trying to connect to my site also on the server. Its causing problems by connecting via ipv6. The software i am running in php doesnt support ipv6 thus i get errors. How do i force the console app (which is using webclient) to use ipv4 connection/ip address rather then ipv6?

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on how the underlying operating system and network resolves the name.  If your dns returns an IPv6 address, that's what it will use. There's nothing in .Net that can change that, unless you want to write your own dns lookup code to ignore ip6 responses.

Comment: I am talking about the ip address and bot lookup. Like instead of sending ::1 to the server send 127.0.0.1. I know changing browsers (chrome to firefox) changed how my ip was sent. Now i'd like .NET to do it

Comment: You would have to rewrite the application to handle that scenario, or you could disable IPv6 functionality on the system that's running it. That would force it to use IPv4, unless the application was written in such a way that it only uses IPv6 interfaces.